# c++ pointer issue involving delete operation

Tags: c++

Here's a problem, and I am supposed to figure out what the bug is.

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

void foo(Node* n) {
    delete n->next;
}

Node* create(int x, Node* n) {
    Node* n1 = new Node();
    n1->data = x;
    n1->next = n;

    return n1;
}

int main(void) {
    Node* n1 = create(1, NULL);
    Node* n2 = create(2, n1);

    foo(n2);
    Node* n3 = create(3, NULL);

    n1->data = 42;

    printf("%d\n", n3->data);
    delete n2;
    delete n3;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, the code prints the number 42, instead of the value 3 as expected.
I narrowed it down by using debugger to the following issue:
When the line `Node* n3 = create(3, NULL)` gets called, inside the create method, the n1 created by the first line is actually the same address as the n1 that was FIRST created and then deleted. This is contrary to what happened when n2 was created, where the n1 inside the create function actually has a new address.
So for some reason, it seems that after the delete operation in `foo`, the `new Node()` operation no longer returns a new address.

FYI, when the lines `foo(n2)` and `Node* n3 = create(3, NULL)` are swapped, then 3 is printed by the code, which is the expected behavior.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `foo(n2)` is called, `n1` and `n2->next` both point to the same `Node` object.  `foo` then `delete`s that object.  At that point, `n1` and `n2->next` both point to an invalid location.  That means that the behavior of your program becomes undefined when you later attempt to assign to `n1->data`.  In this particular case, the object pointed to by `n3` ends up in the same place the object originally pointed to by `n1` was and you end up altering that object through `n1`.  This is not guaranteed though.  Anything, from nothing to a program crash, could happen.

Comment: that makes sense. Can you please help clarify one more thing - so even though I deleted n1, n1 still holds the address number of the object (I confirmed it by printing n1 after foo()). Furthermore, even though n1 still holds the address number, the new Node() operation can still allocate the same memory location corresponding to the n1 address number, right?

Comment: Correct.  `delete` doesn't change the value of any pointers.  It only destroys the object pointed to.  The pointers are then said to be "dangling".  Any further attempt to dereference any pointers that pointed to the `delete`d object results in undefined behavior.  The allocator serving `new` similarly doesn't know or care about any pointers pointing to regions it's allocated.  It tracks what memory has been allocated (with `new`) and released (with `delete`) internally, and can and will re-use memory once it has been released.

Comment: Last question - so if during the creation of n3, the system allocates a different memory location from that of the deleted n1, then at what point will the program crash? I guess it's `n1->data = 42`, since n1 no longer represents a node structure? But that doesn't explain why when I swap `foo(n2)` and `Node* n3 = create(3, NULL)`, the program compiles successfully and print out 3.

Comment: Your program may or may not crash, and if it does it could be anywhere.  The likely spot would be the assignment of `n1->data = 42`, but undefined behavior can time travel.  If you invoke any undefined operation, the behavior of your entire program becomes undefined.  These sorts of things can get very tricky to debug for that reason.  I would recommend you always use smart pointers (i.e. `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`) when dealing with dynamic allocations for that reason.

Comment: But if n1 gets deleted, how can the operation `n1->data = 42` be even possible? After all, n1 no longer represents a node, since I assume everything in that address is deleted. So `n1->data` is meaningless, right?

Comment: The compiler will compile that to an assembly instruction like `mov DWORD PTR [eax], 42` where `eax` is replaced with whatever register holds the value of `n1`.  It doesn't matter to the CPU if there's a live `Node` object at that location; it will happily store the value `42` to that location in memory.  It could be that there's nothing there and the write doesn't do anything, or it could be that some other unrelated object has been allocated there and that `42` clobbers some other object's internal state. That's why the behavior is undefined. Anything can happen, and most of anything is bad.

Comment: @MilesBudnek deleting a pointer makes any pointers to that object hold an invalid pointer value. *Usually* the representation doesn't change but it might. *Any* attempted use of the value is either undefined or implementation-defined.

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid write.  `foo(n2)` effectively calls `delete n1`, and then you allocate another `Node`; in your case, the newly allocated memory has the same address as `n1` (which is now available since you freed the memory).

If you run your program under `valgrind`, it'll report the invalid write.